# Terraform GCP - Error waiting for Setting usage export bucket.: Required 'read' permission for 'gcp-bucket'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm presently receiving the above error message when creating a GCP project via Terraform and setting the Compute Engine Usage Export. The part of my config that deploys this is:

```
"google_project_usage_export_bucket": {
      "usage_export": {
        "project": "${google_project.project_name.project_id}",
        "bucket_name": "gcp-bucket",
        "prefix": "test-export"
      }
    }
```

The service account I'm using to deploy the project has been given the 'Storage Object Viewer' permission on the bucket.
I'm not sure what other 'read' permission it needs because it's not explicit enough.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that the service account used to access the cloud storage is Compute Engine service account " xxxxxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" with storage object admin role. The API scopes for  the storage reader for the vm instance should be read/write.
Please use the document [1] {https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control} for the  permissions and roles for the bucket.

Please also provide more details related to your issue like the Permission tab on your cloud console for " gcp-bucket " bucket?

Let's try a simple test by exporting a file from your VM instance to GCS to see if there is any IAM permission or VM scope issue here.

1- Inside the VM instance, run ' gcloud auth list ' to verify if  the service account “ xxxxxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" is there and active ; if it is not the case, please run ' gcloud config set account xxxxxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"

2- If it is not there then we will need to add it to the auth list with their own .json key by following this document [2] {https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account }, Then you can continue with  ' gcloud config set account “ xxxxxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"

3- Run the following command to create a sample text file in your Cloud Shell: ' echo "this is a sample file" > sample.txt '

4- You can create another bucket if you don't want to use  "gcp-bucket"  ' gsutil mb -l us-central1 gs://test '

5- Run the following command to copy the file to the bucket "gcp-bucket
" gsutil cp sample.txt gs://gcp-bucket

6- List the items in the bucket ' gsutil ls gs://YOURBUCKET '

- The idea is to discriminate where the issue is happening: VM Instance, IAM, GCS.

Comment: This was the answer - it needed the Storage Object Admin role, even though the error message only listed 'Read' permission, which it already had. Thanks very much! :)